# Which way would you design this inter communication between devices

Tags: android

I have a design question. How would you approach this?

I have a pool of devices. Device A wants to communicate to device B and starts a chatting session. I see two options here and PLEASE let me know if there is a third option that is more common:

1-Device A send a msg to server which PUSH it to B and vice versa. This is done for every text msg.

2- Device A sends a message to server and then PUSH msg to Device B saying it wants to chat with its IP info. Device A starts a socket server. Device B (as a client) connect using sockets to Device A. Text messages happens

Please let me know whats the appropriate design or what I should consider

PS 1: By Push msg, I am referring to cloud messaging.

PS 2: The devices are not close. So wifi or Bluetooth is out of question

Comment: No answer to this? There has to be experts in here :)

Comment: As per my understanding the first option look like UDP and second one look like TCP :)

Comment: There was a pond of discussion happened here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198016/suitable-design-pattern-for-a-simple-chat-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is

> How would you approach this?

I'll give you my point of view. This answer is not the right answer, as **the** right answer doesn't exist.

How you'd approach this depends on how much chat you're going to expect. Simply said, method 1 is easier to implement, but method 2 is lighter on the server. There's a couple pro's and con's though.
Method 1:

1. Allows for group chats easily. You can just let the server send it to everybody.
2. Easy to implement. Or well, easiest of the 2.
3. Allows for chat history. You can store the history on the server, and allow the user to look it up with a different device.
4. Heavy on the server. Once you get a couple chats going, say 20 at a time, a cheap server is going to start getting strained.

Method 2, also called [hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)):

1. Very light on the server. The only message that ever has to be sent is one saying "someone wants to chat with you, find him here".
2. Difficult to implement. You can probably find a library for it, but actually implementing hole-punching yourself can be rather tricky.
3. Less stable. If the connection is lost, you have to restart the chat.

**tl;dr:**
If you are new to making chat systems (or any other online system), do not go for hole-punching, unless you're looking for a challenge. Use method 1.

As you ask about other methods too, I wouldn't know any of top of my head but the dangerous waters of P2P. This method is pretty much hole-punching for multiple clients. A warning ahead of time, this can be terribly difficult to implement. The idea is relatively simple.
You've got a server, doing pretty much the same as with hole punching. You (A) tell it you want to join, the server tells someone else (B) you want to join.
(B) sends you a message, and starts up a connection with you.

Now (C) wants to join. The server redirects (C) to (B), and they both connect. (B) is connected to (A), and tells (A) and (C) to connect. Now all (A), (B) and (C) have direct connections to each other.

(A) sends a message. This is done by sending it to both (B) and (C), pretty straightforward.

Say now that another user, (D), wants to join but can't connect to (A) directly. He can however connect to (B).

(A) sends another message. (B) gets this message, and sends it out to everybody he knows. This way (D) also gets this message. However, (C) gets it twice. To prevent it from displaying twice, every client keeps a list of sent and received messages, and refrains from re-sending a message they already sent once.

As said, this would be terribly difficult to implement, and often not worth it. One of the issues of this would be that say user (B) goes offline, and the server knows only of him, no one can connect to the existing "chat" any more. To handle this the server would have to keep track of every client. It's easier on the server than method 1, but heavier than method 2. It does allow for group chats though. For more explanation on P2P, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer

Comment: Wow that's is pretty detailed answer. Thank you. If there is a third common method then please share

Comment: Thanks a lot .. yea I will stick to method 1 I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use option 1.  The issue with option 2 is that the device might be behind a firewall or a NAT server.  So it may not even know it's "true" IP address.  For example, the device's IP is going to be something like 192.168.0.25, but to the outside world it's going to be a public IP address, not 192.168.0.25.  And even if the device listened on a port, the firewall might prevent the incoming connection.

Comment: upvoting for the pitfall to watch for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first option is the best one, because of (but not limited to) the following reasons:

1. Cloud Messaging is implemented and supported by someone else! Google Cloud Messaging, for example, is managed by Google and they have much higher resources than you can probably manage. This means you don't have to worry about *how* a message gets to its recipient, you can just be assured that it does!
2. Group conversations can be more easily implemented later if everyone is a "client" and the server is the "host".

Comment: Your second points I very good actually. For your first point, GCM does not only sit on google. You also have to have your own webserver in between GCM and you, right?

Comment: The easiest way is to add a Google Cloud Module into your Android Studio project. "File -> New Module"