# Are there any design pattern for private chatting between 2 people?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I want to create a conversation between 2 people. I implemented a sending message part but have no idea how to implement a viewing message. So, each other people can see the messages other sent.

Should I create 1 more array in inbox class like **incoming_inbox** that contains the messages the other people sent to ?

Or there is any design pattern which can help me solve this problem ?

```
class Receiver:
    def __init__(self, sender_obj, receiver_email):
        """
        :param sender_obj: obj
        :param receiver_email: string
        """
        self.messages = []
        self.sender_email = sender_obj.getEmail()
        self.receiver_email = receiver_email

Class Account:

    def sendMessage(self, receiver_email, message):
        """

        :param receiver_email: string
        :param message: string
        :return: receiver
        """
        receiver = Receiver(self, receiver_email)
        receiver.addMessage(message) #Receiver has array that contains a lot of messages
        self.inbox.addReceiver(receiver) #Inbox has array that contains a lot of receiver

        return receiver
```

Comment: You can find some design patterns here https://www.oodesign.com/. You could try a something like a MessageProvider or IncomingMessageObserver. There are serveral open source messaging applications you can find inspiration. https://github.com/signalapp    or https://bitbucket.org/pidgin/main/src/default/    or  or take a look at the XMPP protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP

Comment: https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ionic3-chat/blob/master/src/providers/chat-service.ts

Comment: https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure of whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1198016/8824174) would help. Its in Java and you have asked about python but similar principles would apply. Also have a look at some [design patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) which would give you more information on what you would require. Have you considered the following points?

- If you are going for only two users in a conversation you could create a central **controller** for the conversation which would provide the interface for interaction between the users. Another way to handle this might be through a **mediator**.

  ```
  class MessageController():
      MsgList=[]
      def getMsgs():
          return MsgList
      def publishMsg(msg):
          MsgList.append(msg)
  ```
- In such a case, you could go ahead and also create a message interface and a user interface and the controller would have a list/collection of messages which could be accessed by the users.
- The previous point would also enable you to create a conversation with more users. Though I understand that the controller is becoming a god object at this point.
- Also if you wish for some kind of access control you could start giving "Roles" to the users. More info on that if you wish in the **decorator** section of the design pattern link.
- Also as Gourang has stated you could use **observers** to reduce the functions of the central controller so as to reduce the amount of responsibility given to that class.

As you can see there is possibly no "correct" way for this. I am relatively new to Software dev and learning myself, so please feel free to give any inputs you would like regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below design pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem##
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern